# Creating multiple pages

Tags: pages

I have a few pages and I'm trying to import subpages into each like this:

```
 wp_insert_post (
  array(
    'post_title' => $something,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_parent' => array(17, 25, 27, 29)
  )
 );
```

So the structure should looks like:

```
first->imported_name
second->imported_name
...
```

But this doesn't work, it creates only 1 subpage. Should I copy that code 5 times for 5 pages?

Comment: `post_parent` does not accept array and WP doesn't support multiple parents for posts in general. It's not clear what you are trying to do, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post_parent` must be a single number, not an array. Each post can have only one parent. If you want to insert posts for multiple parents, use something like this:

```
foreach ( array(17, 25, 27, 29) as $parent )
{
    wp_insert_post (
        array(
            'post_title'  => $something,
            'post_type'   => 'page',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_parent' => $parent
        )
    );
}
```